# How do I find the associated, minimal and embedded prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Given the ideal $I=(x^3,xy,xz^2)\subseteq k[x,y,z]$ how do I find the associated, minimal and embedded prime ideals?

I got the minimal primary decomposition to be $I=(x,y)\cap (x^3,z^2)$ so that the associated primes are $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$, by the first uniqueness theorem.

I'm not sure how I go about finding the rest. I know that the minimal prime ideals have to be the minimal of the associated prime ideals while the rest are embedded, but which is the minimal?

Comment: Something must be wrong in your decomposition, or the given ideal has other generators: $yz^2$ belongs to the decomposition, but is not in $I$.

Comment: @user26857 Does $(x)\cap (x^3,y,z^2)$ look correct? Making $(x)$ and $(x,y,z)$ the associated primes where $(x)$ is the minimal prime and $(x,y,z)$ the embedded prime?

Comment: Yes, this sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw it out there that Macaulay2 gives a great way to find these! And there's a great online interface [here.](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) Here's the code:

[image: Macaulay2 Code]

You can see the language is very intuitive!

Also notice that **decompose** and **minimalPrimes** do the same thing. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.